# The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registred in the machine or application config file

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ado.net

My program is working fine when i do it on my PC, but when anyone else try it open on their PC, it will open the first page but when they click on "login" and program probably need to start working with database they get this error

[image]

I reinstal connectors, do a PM>Install-Package EntityFramework and trying to check app.config but for me it's look fine. Also i have EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll - copy Local - true which should be right.

This is my app.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="Database" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=XXX;user id=XXX;password=XXX;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=XXX;allowuservariables=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDatabaseModelConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.17.0" newVersion="8.0.17.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

They might didn't have any MySql connector installed on their  machine.
Fixed it by installing nuget: MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity

[image]